# Getting images to show on grid-pane dynamically

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

My goal is to display images that are selected from a filechooser activated by button, and add those images to my gridpane. I am able to get the right URL file path name from the file chooser in order to make a correct imageview however when doing so my gridpane does not show any images being added..

```
public void makeBrowseButton(Stage primaryStage) {

    //attach handler
    browseButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();                                                                            // create object
            fileChooser.getExtensionFilters()
                    .addAll(new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Image Files", "*.png", "*.jpg", "*.gif"));    //filter for music files
            //FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG file", "jpg", "jpeg");
            if (!parentPath.equalsIgnoreCase(
                    "")) {                                                                                //go to previous directory if exists
                File parentPathFile = new File(parentPath);
                fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(parentPathFile);
            }
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);

            if (selectedFile != null) {                                                  // display the dialog box
                String wholePath = selectedFile.getPath();
                String name = selectedFile.getName();
                String megaPath = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
                String megaUrl;
                try {
                    megaUrl = Paths.get(megaPath).toUri().toURL().toString();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
                }

                parentPath = selectedFile.getParent();
                System.out.println("wholePath: " + wholePath);
                System.out.println("parent: " + parentPath);
                System.out.println("File Name: " + name);
                System.out.println("megaPath: " + megaUrl);
                //System.out.println("Canonical: " + Canonical);

                Image newAwesomeImage = new Image(megaUrl);
                paneofgridmonkeys.add(new ImageView(newAwesomeImage), 0, 0);
                //ImageView view = new ImageView();
                //view.setImage(newAwesomeImage);
                //paneofgridmonkeys.add(view, 1, 1);
                //paneofgridmonkeys.setConstraints(view, 0, 4);
                //paneofgridmonkeys.add(new Label("Changed the image!"), 0, 1);
                createDisplay(primaryStage);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried multiple ways of insterting an images and these are the filepaths im getting:

```
wholePath: \\jupiter\yr1005\Desktop\20190111_1340501.jpg
parent: \\jupiter\yr1005\Desktop
File Name: 20190111_1340501.jpg
megaPath: file://jupiter/yr1005/Desktop/20190111_1340501.jpg
```

(im using the megapath)

basically when i choose an image from filechooser I get no error but no image is shown after selection. I just get all the print statements in return.. an idea why?

This is my create Display method:

```
   public void createDisplay(Stage primaryStage) {

   primaryStage.setTitle(this.MONKEY_TITLE);
   GridPane paneofgridmonkeys = new GridPane();
   paneofgridmonkeys.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
   paneofgridmonkeys.setVgap(10);
   paneofgridmonkeys.add(browseButton, 10, 10);

   ScrollPane allTehFaces = new ScrollPane(paneofgridmonkeys);
   allTehFaces.setFitToWidth(true);
       primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(allTehFaces, 500, 500));primaryStage.show();
     }
   }
```

Comment: What does the createDisplay method look like?

Comment: I have updated my post to show it. Maybe i should make a createImage method  that i will call at the end of my button method to create the view?

Comment: There's your problem. Try removing this line:   `GridPane paneofgridmonkeys = new GridPane();`

Comment: You're creating a new instance of GridPane using the same variable name (`paneofgridmonkeys`) as the class-scoped instance, which I'm inferring is a class-level variable because it's referenced in `makeBrowseButton`. The ability to create locally-scoped variables with the same name as class-scoped variables (and which then supersede the class variables locally)  is one of the flaws in the design of Java IMO.

Comment: thank youuu! that makes so much more sense now.

Comment: You're very welcome! I corrected my answer and undeleted it, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're problem is in the createDisplay method; specifically this line:

```
   GridPane paneofgridmonkeys = new GridPane();
```

Here you're creating a locally-scoped GridPane called `paneofgridmonkeys`, which must be the name of another class-level variable called `paneofgridmonkeys`, since it's available to `makeBrowseButton`. When you do this in local scope, the new instance you've created becomes the one that's used inside of that method, rather than the class-level instance; thus the class-level one isn't the one being added to your scene, and you're not seeing the changes.

Comment: @billHovath do you know what imports i would need for invalidate and repaint because i cant seem to find it in the Java oi

Comment: I inferred paneofgridmonkeys was an instance of JComponent (or one of it's child classes.) Is that not the case? What class is it?

Comment: no it is you are correct but I am getting 'cannot find symbol' error pointing at invalidate and repaint and i assumed thats missing imports on my part.

Comment: Nm; looks like you're using JavaFX instead of Swing; my bad. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Still no image displayed... should i start thinking about adding the url to an array and then makign a for loop in my create display method to add images.. Been having this issue for quite some time now (i am using javafz sorrry for the confusion).

Comment: Hmm... Maybe adding `paneofgridmonkeys.requestFocus();` before `paneofgridmonkeys.requestLayout();` will help? (Sorry; it's been _forever_ since I did JavaFX)

Comment: Still not displaying and this is all inside the actionHanlder so it should work